# Alternative way to hold members in a data structure

Tags: c++, visual-c++, data-structures, mfc, containers

I need to remember pairs of values for n instances. I know one solution i.e either making a separate class or structure, declare 2 member variable & place it in a list or array.

But is there any other efficient way of doing this in C++/VC++ MFC?

Comment: What's wrong with that approach that makes you look for alternatives (btw you can just use `std::pair`)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a pair using `std::pair<X,Y>` or `std::make_pair(T1, T2)`. You can then store these pairs in data structure of your choice as you would like to modify the

```
std::vector<std::pair<X,Y> > or std::set<std::pair<X,Y> >
```

Answer (score 2):

If the *pairs of **values*** mentioned in the question mean integer values, I think you can use `CArray` of `CPoint` or `CSize` at the expense of code readability.

Sample code:

```
CArray<CPoint, CPoint> Array;
Array.Add(CPoint( 2, 3 ));
Array.Add(CPoint( 2, 4 ));
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use [tr1::tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982771%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Also, described in my [article here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/stl/stl2010.aspx#TupleClass).

Comment: N.B. `std::tuple` is a fully-variadic type in C++0x.

Comment: Yes, but current implementation of VC doesnt support variadic templates. It uses nested header inclusion.
Via <tuple> header it comes into std namespace, but it actually in tr1 only.

Comment: Oh yeah [you're right](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/04/06/c-0x-core-language-features-in-vc10-the-table.aspx) whoops

Answer (score 0):

There are loads of other ways of doing it but thats probably one of the most efficient way.  I can think of several really inefficient ways of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do worse than check out [Boost::Tuple<>](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html)

> A tuple (or n-tuple) is a fixed size collection of elements. Pairs,
>   triples, quadruples etc. are tuples. In a programming language, a
>   tuple is a data object containing other objects as elements. These
>   element objects may be of different types.
>
> Tuples are convenient in many circumstances. For instance, tuples make
>   it easy to define functions that return more than one value.

Answer (score 0):

If one of the values is a key for the other, you could use a `Dictionary` or other map-type data structure.

<strike>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx</strike> (.NET only)

As MSalters pointed out, MFC has its own map type as well, [`CMap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s897094z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Also check out [`std::map`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28C%2B%2B_container%29) if you want to use something similar in non-CLI or MFC code.

Comment: What part of "C++" didn't you understand?

Comment: @Martinho: It seems you missed the part of the question where LLL implies he is using VC++.

Comment: VC++ is a compiler or an IDE. If the question is about C++/CLI, it does not show it anywhere.

Comment: @Martinho: A compiler that supports the usage of .NET objects and classes. Like `Dictionary`. If you're really that annoyed by it I'll mention `std::map` as well, though.

Comment: No, the [VC++](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/visual-c%2b%2b/info) compiler does not support .NET classes when compiling C++.

Comment: I see, I was not aware of that specific distinction. Regardless, I did add the mention of `std::map`, so it's fine.

Comment: Well, if you were expecting me to remove the downvote... I can't. It's not my downvote :(

Comment: Not my downvote either, but MFC is the giveaway that you can't use .Net. Then again, MFC _does_ have `CMap<Key, Key&, Value, Value&>` (yeah, those references are redundant and a bit weird I agree).

Comment: @MSalters: Oh, thanks for the note. Added that info to my answer.